# How to not disable background when using mat-dialog-container

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, frontend

I wanna know if is possible to not disable the background when opening a dialog with mat-dialog-container, i wanna continue using the background screen while using the dialog at the same time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmnBf.png), im using angular btw.

I havent tried much to be honest.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should start by exploring the documentation. There is `hasBackdrop` property that you can set to false in the `MatDialogConfig` ((docs)[https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig]) when opening the dialog. It will disable the backdrop, making the dialog non-modal, i.e. user should be able to interact with the background. You can probably make the dialog droppable if needed by playing around with `cdk-drag` (docs (here)[https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview])